# What does the GlowPadBackport readme mean?

Tags: android, android-source, android-library, nineoldandroids, backport

> This library will NOT do anything that is not strictly needed for this to build/work. Since this class has since been removed from AOSP, this library should be considered DEPRECATED. No efforts will be put into it, including merging PRs, for anything but very critical issues.
>
> > A backport of the Android 4.2 GlowPadView that works on the SDK on API levels 4+.
>
> It is heavily based upon Google's own internal implementation of the
>   GlowPadView found in Android 4.2 Jelly Bean, but ported to be able to
>   run on the Android SDK up from version 1.6 (API level 4, codename
>   Donut). It uses Reflection in a couple of method calls to access some
>   hidden APIs, so it might break on some Android version, or in the
>   future. I tried limiting the usage of Reflection as much as possible,
>   but those three methods did not have any alternatives.
>
> I'm releasing my own code under the same Apache 2.0 license the
>   underlying Android code is licensed under. Android code is written by
>   Google, and licensed under that same Apache 2.0 license.
>
> GlowPadBackport relies on NineOldAndroids, an awesome backport of the
>   Android 3+ Animation APIs made by Jake Wharton.

Taken from here:

https://github.com/frakbot/GlowPadBackport

I did not get anything !

Comment: It means that the library and/or its part were available in the previous versions but not in the recent versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This library will NOT do anything that is not strictly needed for this to build/work.

We won't include any code that improve performance or add functionalities.
We only do bug fixes.

> Since this class has since been removed from AOSP, this library should be considered DEPRECATED. No efforts will be put into it, including merging PRs, for anything but very critical issues.

We are not gonna spend time making merge with new versions of the dependencies or submitted code, unless we are talking about a bug fix.

> A backport of the Android 4.2 GlowPadView that works on the SDK on API levels 4+.

We rewrote a UI component that was originally written for Android 4.2 and made it work for Android 1.6+.

> It is heavily based upon Google's own internal implementation of the GlowPadView found in Android 4.2 Jelly Bean, but ported to be able to run on the Android SDK up from version 1.6 (API level 4, codename Donut).

Such UI component has never been made available to software with a public API, so we went into Android Open Source Project repository and copied the code Google wrote.

> It uses Reflection in a couple of method calls to access some hidden APIs, so it might break on some Android version, or in the future. I tried limiting the usage of Reflection as much as possible, but those three methods did not have any alternatives.

The component itself use non public API, we got around this with the use of a programming technique called [Reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) which is anything but good.

> I'm releasing my own code under the same Apache 2.0 license the underlying Android code is licensed under. Android code is written by Google, and licensed under that same Apache 2.0 license.

We are not eager for money.

> GlowPadBackport relies on NineOldAndroids, an awesome backport of the Android 3+ Animation APIs made by Jake Wharton.

We need that library to make fancy animations.